# Thunderbird doesn't work with postfix/dovecot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, thunderbird

My environment:

- ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- postfix 3.4.13
- dovecot 2.3.7.2

Setup is extremely simple. I configured postfix via built-in master as an internet site host. Dovecot (I use it as IMAP server) settings are all default. Now, I'm able to connect to this server with any mail client at my hands (outlook, eM Client) and do routine mailwork except Thunderbird.

When I try to setup my account in Thunderbird I got such window for infinity:
[image: Thunderbird setup window]

On server side I see these suspicious entries in `mail.log` whenever I try to test my settings in thunderbird settings windows (test passes OK):

```
postfix/smtpd[13695]: improper command pipelining after EHLO from me.example.com[192.168.1.25]: QUIT\r\n
postfix/smtpd[13695]: disconnect from me.example.com[192.168.1.25] ehlo=1 quit=1 commands=2
```

I specifically simplified this setup because I have a fully fledged mail server with authentication, SSL, DKIM, etc. but I'm also unable to use thunderbird with it (behavior is exactly the same).

I'm out of ideas how to make thunderbird to connect to my server. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you get this error when trying to add a mailaccount to thunderbird and click on "test settings"? as far as I know, this error is normal and unrelated to your problem. On my mailserver, I have seen this error, too - and thunderbird works with my mailserver like a charm... Could you describe more detailed what happens when you try to use thunderbird (for more than just "test settings"), and what errors are seen in the logs (if any)?

Comment: When I click `Done` button Thunderbird just keeps spinning that damn circle next to `checking password...` text for infinite. There's also nothing related to connection from thunderbird in server logs.

Comment: And I know thunderbird works (worked?) flawlessly with postfix/dovecot since I done such setup a couple of years ago and everything was running just fine.

Comment: if you do that with your real server ( port 993 for imaps, 465 / 587 for submission ) nothing shows in the logs ? are you sure this is not a firewall issue ? dovecot logs per default every incoming connection, if there is no log entry, dovecot didn't see an incoming connection...

Comment: I do see log entries when I test connection by clicking on `Re-test`. But when I click on `Done` there's nothing in logs from thunderbird. Firewall rules are not the issue since other mail clients work just fine.

Comment: Have you reset your thunderbird profile (or deleted any incorrect accounts from its settings)? Maybe everything could be working, just repeatedly using the Thunderbird setup has lead to a different configuration being used than you expected from the shorter quick setup dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't really know what it all was about. But it seems it was a certificate issue. I renamed IMAP server and reissued let's encrypt certificate. After these steps thunderbird was able to connect to IMAP server.

Answer (score 2):

**Configure your Thunderbird to use the TLS-secured ports, behaviour with your test is likely *not* "exactly the same".**

The log you show in your question for your simplified test likely says little about the actual problem you are attempting to diagnose.

The thunderbird connection test simply disconnects after not being offered secure authentication by the SMTP server on port 25. This is not unusual with the settings in your screenshot. Port 25 is used for receiving internet mail from other servers. Typically you would only offer authenticated submission on port 465, secured via TLS (and IMAPs via port 993, also secured via TLS).

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I have a fully fledged mail server with authentication, SSL, DKIM, etc. Thunderbird won't work with this server either. So TLS, imaps, submission and other security stuff are not the case.

Comment: Connection test is succeeded but account (in thunderbird) isn't created. That's the case!

Comment: @knight_lightning I have the exact same issue and same log with you, how have you solved this at the end?